# creating custom logic for focusing html elements while validating form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been stuck in somewhere around validating the form. I have a nice 10-11 fields in 
my .cshtml page in MVC. Those fields are using data anotations from model and here I
am using client side validations using jquery and unobtrusive javascript. So, validations 
are firing up very good on submit but we need to implement a logic where a user will click on the 
submit button but the page will automatically drags the user to the location of mandatory field.

Assume that all 11 fields in my form are mandatory. user has filled the first two and 
left the third blank .So on submitting the form, the cursor should focus to that control
with the validation message.Due to the length of the page, it should be scrolling up and down
accordingly. And if suppose only first two fields are filled and others are empty,
the validation message should show the 3rd field with the focus on control and then 
if user filled the 3rd field and hit save, it should focus to the fourth field.

On one instance it looks easy and I am trying it with following code snippet on click of submit button.

AS this is the class which mvc uses when validation fires, I select element from the first class like below:

```
 var element = $('#' + $('.input-validation-error:first').attr('id'));
```

once I get the element then I am using the below code:

```
 if (element.selector !== '#undefined') {

// The class "RequiredFeildDropdown" is applied to the control so that I can
 check if that is kendo dropdown and I should focus to that kendo control of the element.

        if (element.hasClass("RequiredFeildDropdown")) {
            element.data("kendoDatePicker").element.focus();
        }

// This class "RequiredFeildDate" has been applied to check whether the kendo control is datepicker
so that I can focus it.

        else if (element.hasClass("RequiredFeildDate")) {
            element.data("kendoDropDownList").focus();
        }
```

// So here comes the real problem.The primaryaddressData contains the collection 
of objects. Actually my page also consists of some table elements that i have created using for loop.

So, while validating , if primaryaddressData.length have `count < 1`,  this div should show.Actually there should 
be atleast one primary address. The div which have table elemets is "primaryaddressErrorMessage"

```
 else {
        if (primaryaddressData.length >= 1) {
            $("#primaryaddressErrorMessage").hide();
        } else {
            $("#primaryaddressErrorMessage").show();
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#primaryaddressErrorMessage").offset().top
            }, 'slow');
            isValid = false;
        }

        element.focus();
```

To make more clear of the second portion,My page also has a div called "primaryaddressErrorMessage" which I have described above

```
<div class="common-box padding25 ">
                                <span id="primaryaddressErrorMessage" class="margin-btm30" style="display: none; color: #ce3a36; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'signikaregular', Arial">Primary Addressed are required.</span>
                                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Common/_AddressPartial.cshtml", Model);}

                            </div>
```

So, This partialview has a set of controls which user uses to add primary address.
When this partial view loads, by using ajax request, I check from database
If this user has atleast one primary address,If yes, I keep its count it
"primaryaddressData"=1 and so when user submits a new primary address,
after an post request to controller, I get the primary address count from 
database and again set "primaryaddressData"= count that I get from database through Json.

As this "primaryaddressData" is global, when user hits save from the main page i.e from the main
view which was containing the above partialview, I check the length of 
"primaryaddressData" and if is having less than one, I will have to focus to

this span having id="primaryaddressErrorMessage"

I am going very hard through this. There might be someone who has also faced this problem in past. So, it could be a duplicate question but I asked it for this particular scenario. Please let me know if some more explanation is required.

Comment: You first code blockcan just be `if (element.length > 0) { element.focus(); }`

Comment: Sir, any example or fiddler can be possible?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the 2nd part of your question (referring to `primaryaddressData`) and what is your trying to do.

Comment: okay. Let me update my question accordingly

Comment: Sir, I updated my question. Please let me know if it still requires more explanation or if I am not able to make you understand of the situation.